# Python Regular Expression Help - Square Brackets and Optional Arguments

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to parse a python command-line argument to send to my host application that talks to some firmware, and the command involves square brackets and an optional argument.

I define a low-level I2C command with the following syntax (quotes added for show):

`i2c##[w##...][r#]`, where

```
i2c##      is the i2c slave address, with ## as two hex digits.
[w##...]   is the write data, with at least two hex digits ##...
[r#]       is the read data, with # being a decimal number
```

I get close with the following regular expression:

```
i2c[A-Fa-f0-9]{2}[[]w[A-Fa-f0-9]{2,}[]]([[]r[0-9]+[]])
```

It is able to pass the greater case:

```
i2cBF[wDEADBEEF][r16]
```

but not the one without the read option, i.e:

```
i2cBF[wDEADBEEF]
```

Would like some help from the mightier regex users. Anyone up for the challenge?

Comment: There is no challenge required here.  All you need is a `?`.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the edit aelor. I'm new to this format.

Comment: Verily. The answer is always the question [mark]. Thanks devnull.

Answer (score 0):

make the last group optional and yes one more thing, if you want to do a literal match do it by escaping the square brackets:

corrected your regex without escaping

```
i2c[A-Fa-f0-9]{2}[[]w[A-Fa-f0-9]{2,}(?:[]]([[]r[0-9]+[]])?)
```

corrected regex with escaping:

```
i2c[A-Fa-f0-9]{2}\[w[A-Fa-f0-9]{2,}\](?:(\[r[0-9]+\])?)
```

Comment: I swear I've tried all of these permutations today, escaped and otherwise, including the question mark I had forgotten to put in the original post. You are correct aelor, but the end-goal is for consistent intended behavior (upon which designs can be based upon). The first incomplete case `i2cBF[wDEADBEEF` results in a 'None' returned from re.match/search, but the second incomplete case `i2CBF[wDEADBEEF][r` returns an actual re match object with the value None given by groups().

Try it here: http://www.pythonregex.com/

Comment: `[[]` is a valid equivalent of `\[`. It's a character class containing an open square bracket.

Comment: If you only want pairs of hex digits, `(?:[A-Fa-f0-9]{2})+` excludes anything with an odd number of digits. You probably don't need to be this strict, but perhaps this us useful as an example.